# When selecting a value from DropDownList a second time. It doesn't use newly selected value. It uses the old values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a div called "ddlFiles". It contains a DropDownList that has a bunch of id's in it. What I am trying to do is get a user to select an id then perform an operation by passing in the selected value.(stored proc needs it) The operation works the first time through. But when I try to select an id again, it uses the old id instead of the new one. So for me to pass in the correct id, I have to get the user to select a new id twice, before it actually takes the second new id.

(NOTE: viewExpensesGrid is the my flexigrid)-not really useful but I thought I'd add it in.

This is my function for getting the selected value from the DropDownList which then passes it to a function:

```
 function getCaseFiles(canMoveExpenses) {
            //create Popup with content from div
            $('#ddlFiles').dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                height: 'auto',
                width: 'auto',
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function () {
                        var dropDownList = document.getElementById("ddlCaseFilesNew");
                        var newCaseDdl = dropDownList.options[dropDownList.selectedIndex].value;
                        //alert("newCaseDdl = " + newCaseDdl);

                        var oldCaseFile = $("#hidCaseFile").val();
                        //alert(oldCaseFile);

                        if (newCaseDdl != -1) {
                            moveCasefile(canMoveExpenses, newCaseDdl, oldCaseFile);
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                            $("#viewExpensesGrid").flexReload();//simply refresh flexigrid
                        }
                        else {
                            showMessage("Error. Please Select a Value From The Lists.");
                        }
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        $("#viewExpensesGrid").flexReload();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

And here is my div = "ddlFiles":

```
<div id="ddlFiles">
    <label>
        Select new CaseFile:</label>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCaseFilesNew" DataSourceID="dsCaseFiles"
        DataTextField="Display" DataValueField="FileID" 
        OnPreRender="ddl_PreRender" Width="300px"/>
</div>
```

My stored procedure requires a new CaseId and an old CaseId, the hidCaseFile is a hiddenField. (this already contains the old file ID.

Comment: did you debugged getCaseFiles function? If not, I strongly suggest you to do that analyzing if var dropDownList gets what you expect.

Comment: I just figured out how to debugg it. I am currently debugging it. So far it does everything right the first time I execute it, it gets the correct values etc. But the second time I create the popup and try to get the values. It keeps grabbing the previous values I selected.

Comment: var newCaseDdl = dropDownList.options[dropDownList.selectedIndex].value;

Comment: that's where it for some reason gets the old value assigned instead of a new value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
var dropDownList = document.getElementById("ddlCaseFilesNew");
```

with this

```
var dropDownList = $("#<%= ddlCaseFilesNew.ClientID %>");
```

When executing, server controls have an Id that is different from the one specified in the ID tag, so you should get it using its ClientID wich is not "ddlCaseFilesNew".

Comment: I will try this and report back. Thank you though, didn;t know this

Comment: I tried it but in the debugger dropDownList evaluates to "undefined"